# itextsharp image won't resize - takes up most of page

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I have an image I am putting on a PDF via itextsharp. When I use ScalePercent or ScaleAbsoluteWidth or ScaleAbsoluteHeight it has no effect. The image when it is rendered on the PDF always takes up whatever space is available on the page (it comes up huge).

Here is my code.

```
var chartImage = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
Chart1.SaveImage(chartImage, ChartImageFormat.Png);
iTextSharp.text.Image imageForChart = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(chartImage.GetBuffer());

imageForChart.ScaleAbsoluteHeight(5f);
imageForChart.ScaleAbsoluteWidth(5f);

Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
string pageTitle = "Event Recap Report";
dictionary.Add("Started", tbStartDate.Text);
dictionary.Add("Ended", tbEndDate.Text);
PDFDocument x = new PDFDocument(pageTitle, PageSize.LETTER, 15, 15, 40, 15);

x.UserName = _currentUser.FullName;
x.WritePageHeader(1, ref dictionary);
x.WriteImage(ref imageForChart);
x.WriteGrid(ref grdEventRecap);
x.WritePageFooter();
x.Finish(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try set the Absolute Position like this:

```
var imageForChart = Image.GetInstance(chartImage.GetBuffer());
imageForChart.SetAbsolutePosition(positionX, positionY);
image.ScaleAbsoluteHeight(5f);
image.ScaleAbsoluteWidth(5f);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
string imagePath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/images");
iTextSharp.text.Image png = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagePath + "/myimage.png");
png.ScaleToFit(520, 74);
doc1.Add(png);
```

Use `ScaleToFit()` to resize your image.

Answer (score 0):

I am embarrassed to say that I discovered that we actually have a wrapper around itextsharp, and the WriteImage method in that wrapper was scaling to fit.  My solution was to add a new method which did not do this automatic scale to fit.